# In Function programming languages like scala, what is the approach to stop iterating over a collection? Eg; Return true if given has 0 in it

Tags: scala, functional-programming

In Function programming languages like scala, what is the approach to stop iterating over a collection? Eg; Return true if given has 0 in it.

Given array could be size 100 with 0 as the first element. How to achieve this using pure FP in scala?

With imperative approach, it is usually a if (check for terminate condition) followed by a break to stop iterating.

I am a beginner with FP & scala. Can someone help in clarifying?

Comment: Recursion, check stop condition, return. Exactly the same. Or even better, use higher-order methods which have an early return, like `find`. BTW, do not use **Arrays**.

Comment: Agreed not to use Arrays. These are questions to practice that brought in Array. Even with List, I was not able to find a method for early termination.  Slight deviation - Are there any books on Higher Order Methods in Scala.  Though I am comfortable with DS, awareness to such HOF like find is the gap in my learning.  Could you plese suggest any references @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez

Comment: `reduce` is usually available. There are likely other things that are more specialised versions of `reduce`, as well. FP also usually has lazy chains of operations, so you might not need to explicitly specify "if this then stop" but rather "execute these, here is a condition" and as soon as the condition is satisfied, the chain will stop without you having to specify it.

Comment: You can use a lazy right fold with a binary function `f` that is non-strict in its second argument. Alternatively you can use continuation passing style. Then you can decide within `f` whether to call the continuation.

Comment: @VLAZ `reduce` does not allow early return

Comment: @dexter2305 Not a book but a web page, the [**Scaladoc**](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/immutable/List.html). Still, if you want an early return, the simples method is recursion.

Answer (score 2):

If you take a look a API of `List`s, `Set`s, `Vector`s, `Map`s, etc you'll see a lot of utilities like: `reduce`, `fold`, `foldLeft`, `foldRight`, `map`, etc.

Majority of functions assumes that you can only return result after traversing whole collection. Some process only until condition is met e.g. `.takeWhile(cond)` or takes only a particular example that meets condition e.g. `find(condition)`. Quite often it happens that what you try to do with one loop is a combination of a several of simpler function e.g.

```
var index = 0;
var result = 0;
// add all elements until first element bigger than 100
while (index < list.size) {
  if (list(index) > 100)
    break;
  index++;
  result += list(index);
}
```

could be expressed functionally as:

```
list.takeWhile(i => i > 100).sum
```

The ability to express more and more complex logic will improve as you will learn and use more and more of these methods. If you don't mind iterating through whole collection, `fold`, `reduce` and similar usually allows you to do with your data whatever you want.

However, if you still do not know how to implement something, because you have to e.g. filter, combine and decide to stop iterating to avoid noop loops, you can always revert to tail recursive call:

```
@scala.annotation.tailrec // annotation ensured that compiler will optimize body
def myOperation(unprocessedData: List[Int], resultSoFar: Int): Int =
  unprocessedData match {
    case head :: tail =>
      val newResult = resultSoFar + head
      myOperation(tail, newResult) // to enable tailrec instead of backtracking
                                   // you pass partial results as argument
                                   // and compiler will rewrite it underneath
                                   // into while with break
    case Nil =>
      resultSoFar                  // final result
  }
```

TL;DR

- try using build-in functions like `.map`, `.collect`, `.filter`, `.drop`, `.dropWhile`, `.take`, `.takeWhile` for building what you need
- if too difficult, try using `fold`, `foldLeft`, `foldRight`, `reduce`
- if still to difficult, try using tail recursion - this is basically safer version of `while`-`break` so with that yo should be able to always implement what you want

Answer (score 0):

You could use `exists`

There are many types of immutable collections and they won't inherit `exists` from a common ancestor, but you'll find it there by different means.

Such `assert(List(0,1).exists(_ == 0))`

Under the hood would do:

```
override final def exists(p: A => Boolean): Boolean = {
    var these: List[A] = this
    while (!these.isEmpty) {
      if (p(these.head)) return true
      these = these.tail
    }
    false
  }
```

or `assert(scala.collection.immutable.ArraySeq(0,1).exists(_ == 0))`

which would call to:

```
 def exists(p: A => Boolean): Boolean = {
    var res = false
    val it = iterator
    while (!res && it.hasNext) res = p(it.next())
    res
  }
```